# RegEx to get text form string between double quotes which contains at lest any one like <, <=, >, >=, <>,

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

RegEx to get text form string between double quotes which contains at lest any one like

`:=, &&, ||, ==, <, >, <=, >=, <>, &, +, -, *, /, ? .`

Code:

```
 script = "if(a<=b, strcat(\" userid <= 'tom' \",\" and test = 1\", \" and test >= 10 \"), nop());";
string tempScript = (script ?? "").Trim();

var functionMatches = Regex.Matches(tempScript, @"Some RegEx");
if (functionMatches != null && functionMatches.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Match fm in functionMatches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fm.Value);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Eg:

```
Input :- 
    "if(a<=b, strcat(" userid <= 'tom' "," and test = 1", " and test >= 10 "), nop());"

Output :-

    1) " userid <= 'tom' "

    2) " and test >= 10 "
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post what you tried? Also it is always better including examples (sample inputs/expected outputs) or explaining clearly what you want exactly (e.g., are you expecting strings containing just one bit between double quotes or more than one). Additionally, are you only interested in a regex solution?

Comment: I tryed but i am not getting RegEx for getting double quotes string which conatins any string like <=, >= ... I need RegEx.

Comment: As said, regex is not the alpha and omega of string management, you can try different approaches. You should show whatever you have tried; remember how SO works: you have to show us that you did some effort by your own. What is clear is that the code you have posted does not say anything. And you haven't still defined your problem property.

Comment: @ThulasiRam I think you have missed '=' character in the question description. You also could add some clear examples or at least an example to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Tafari: I need get text between double quotes which conatins any string like <=, >= ...

Comment: @ThulasiRam are you using if as an input? How so?

Comment: @Tafari: "if" is a string we are building dynamic script functions....

Comment: @ThulasiRam example is incorrect there is no `" test = 'd' "` in the input string.

Comment: @ThulasiRam I have provided an answer which produces same output as in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it appears to be not that simple...

I would recommend first looking for all strings between double quotes **"..."** then checking every string if it contains the special characters you provided. So it would be like this:

**Regex**:

`(?<=\")[^,]+?(?=\")`

`^.+?(<=|>=|<>|\|\||:=|&&|==|<|>|&|\+|-|\*|/|\?).+?$`

**Code:**

```
string pattern = "(?<=\")[^,]+?(?=\")";
string patternSpecial = @"^.+?(<=|>=|<>|\|\||:=|&&|==|<|>|&|\+|-|\*|/|\?).+?$";
string input = "if(a<=b, strcat(\" userid <= 'tom' \",\" and test = 1\", \" and test >= 10 \"), nop());";  

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(m.Value, patternSpecial))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(m.Value, patternSpecial).Value);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

> userid <= 'tom'
>
> and test >= 10

---

Using just one pattern and less C# code:

**Regex**:

```
\"([^"]+?(<=|>=|<>|\|\||:=|&&|==|<|>|&|\+|-|\*|/|\?).+?)\"
```

**Code:**

```
string pattern = "\"([^\"]"+@"+?(<=|>=|<>|\|\||:=|&&|==|<|>|&|\+|-|\*|/|\?).+?)"+"\"";
string input = "if(a<=b, strcat(\" userid <= 'tom' \",\" and test = 1\", \" and test >= 10 \"), nop());";  

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

> userid <= 'tom'
>
> and test >= 10

Comment: @ThulasiRam that's true, however it's easier to understand them when they are seprate. But I also provided one regex which does the job as well : ) Cheers happy I could help.